# Calculate (n) workdays from a given date, using a calendar table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, calculated-columns, impala

This question was first posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331759/calculate-n-workdays-from-a-given-date-using-a-calendar-table)

As shown on below image, I have two tables;

- **Customer** : with about 4 million records; and 3 columns

[Customer] : Customer ID - (*primary key*)

[Date] : Creation date

[Num_Days] : Number of working days to calculate the [next_wkday] in the query result.

- **Calendar** : with all calendar days; and 3 columns

[ref_date] : dates

[civil_util] : when (1) -> workday; when (0) -> non working day

[year]

[Data set, and Query Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcBcx.jpg)

I need to get the **query_result** with the three columns of Customer Table and a calculated date [next_wkday], representing the number of working days [Num_Days] after each customer Creation date, jumping the zeros (*non working days*) in the [civil_util] column.

I've created the query below to calculate the [next_wkday] using the Lead() function. But is not a solution because the **offset parameter** must be a constant, and we need to use the [Num_Days] value for each Creation Date:

```
    select *,
                Lead (to_date(ref_date),5) OVER (ORDER BY to_date(ref_date)) AS next_wkday,
                datediff(Lead (to_date(ref_date),5) OVER (ORDER BY 
     to_date(ref_date)),ref_date) as days_diff
            from calendar
            where
                ref_date >= to_date(now())
                and civil_util = 1
                limit 1
```

Basicaly I need to solve two problems:
1 - Must be a query to perform the calculation Because I don't have the profile to create functions in the database.

2 - I need to design a query that achive the ***Query result***, shown in the image, that will able to join both, the Customer table and the calculation query.

So, I need to find another solution. And that solution must work in two engines:

1. Impala version : impalad version 2.12.0-cdh5.16.2
2. Oracle 11g

I need to reinforce, for performance puposes, that the Customer table has 4 billion records approximatly.

Can anyone help please?
My best regards

I've tried to join the view that calculates the [next_wkday] with the Customer table and achieved *no success*.

Tried also the Query below where, instead of calculating the date [next_wkday], it would add the non work days (civil_util = 0) to [Num_days], for each Customer, as shown below: (*but didn't worked*)

```
SELECT  T.CUSTOMER_ID,
        T.CREATED_DATE,
        SUM(C.CIVIL_UTIL) WORK_DAYS,
        T.NUM_DAYS + 1 - SUM(C.CIVIL_UTIL) NEXT_WKDAY
  FROM  CALENDAR C,
        CUSTOMER T
  WHERE C.REF_DATE BETWEEN T.CREATED_DATE AND T.CREATED_DATE + T.NUM_DAYS
  GROUP BY T.CUSTOMER_ID,
           T.CREATED_DATE,
           T.NUM_DAYS
```

I remind that Customer_ID is a Primary Key.

My best regards

Comment: I'm seeking to achieve an impala solution as well. I think in db.stackexchange I'll get only an Oracle version. So, I think it's fair continue to search for a total solution.

Comment: in which case, you should a) edit your question to add a link the question over on db.stackexchange (which really ought to have been posted here on stackoverflow in the first place) indicating that you have an answer for the oracle side already, and b) remove the Oracle tag from this question. Oh, and add the sample data as text to save someone else having to type it out.

Comment: @Boneist I saw your Oracle solution, and the query worked; but as I said, the customer table has 4 million records. It's running since you've posted, and didn't finished yet. Keeping Oracle tag here, can give other members to show different solutions.
Regarding replacing the image for adding data as sanple text, I don't know how to do that. But I promise you that I'll seek for the way to do it.
I'll insert a link to dba.stackexchange as you sugested.
Many thanks to you for all your guidance.

Comment: this join causes cross join and cause perf problem `WHERE C.REF_DATE BETWEEN T.CREATED_DATE AND T.CREATED_DATE + T.NUM_DAYS`. Just an idea, can you capture distinct dates, number of days from customer table and put them into a stg table. Join stg with the calendar table to calculate NEXT_WKDAY, WKDAY etc. Then join this new table back to the customer table on dates, number of days.

Comment: Hi @Koushik Roy. I've posted a link to the solution presented in [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331759/calculate-n-workdays-from-a-given-date-using-a-calendar-table) _italic_ **bold**. The answer works but is taking to much time to execute. (more than 1 hour... I've interrupted in the meantime).
The Customer_ID already is an unique value.

Comment: i tried to give you an alternate solution. If you want to do everything in one step, SQL will take time and thats the reason i was saying to split the process up.

Comment: @LEOPOLDO perhaps you could edit the join conditions to add an upper limit of the rows to match against (e.g. something like `and cust.create_date + 7 + cust.num_days*2 >= cal.ref_date`); that should reduce the number of rows to be processed by the analytic function

Comment: I will try your Idea @Boneist. 
unfortunately for me Koushik Roy I can't split the process. This Query will run on Impala where I don't have an administrator profile to create tables in Run mode.